# Upgrade to Spring boot 2 breaks Groovy-Eclipse compiler

Tags: spring, spring-boot, groovy

I have a mixed java/groovy project with spring boot 1.5 with groovy-eclipse compiler version 2.4 I think? (I think because groovy-all/groovy-compiler/groovy-batch versions do not line up exactly?) Everything compiles fine, I had no issues. Been working this way for about a year or more.

Today I upgraded to spring-boot 2.0.3.RELEASE and now I'm getting:

```
Error:(1, -1) Groovy-Eclipse: Groovy:Internal groovy compiler error.
```

On every single groovy file.

I looked for whether spring-boot 2 and groovy are compatible but couldn't really find any answers.

It's very odd that this would happen as I have not changed the groovy portion of the code at all.

Here are some relevant POM settings:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- 2.8.0-01 and later require maven-compiler-plugin 3.1 or higher -->
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.2-01</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.3-01</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you ever got this resolved, but I had the exact same issue and upgrading the version dependencies from Bintray as suggested in the following link seemed to do the trick. Hope it helps:
https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/425